# How to extract particular data from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I am facing a small problem with a **.json file**. I would like to know how to extract **particular** data in Python3

This is my code :

```
with open("followers_log.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(type(data))#dict
    print(data["data"][0]["username"])
```

My code works but only displays the first result. I would like to display all keys with the name **"username"**
I've been searching on Google since yesterday but I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem.

Example of my json file

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "Example",
            "username": "example"
        },
        {
            "id": "456",
            "name": "example2",
            "username": "example2"
        },
        {
            "id": "789",
            "name": "example3",
            "username": "example3"
        },
```

An idea?
Thank you

Comment: If you wanted all results, what did you expect the `[0]` to do?

Comment: because that way I had no error in return when I executed my code

Comment: Sure, but I meant, why not use a loop from 0,1,2 to get more than just `[0]` element??

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for each in data["data"]:
    print(each["username"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(data["data"][0]["username"])
```

In the posted code the [0]-part refers to the first item in the list denoted as "data". (Indicated by the []-tags in your json-file.)

So, [0] refers to the following:

```
{
"id": "123",
"name": "Example",
"username": "example"
}
```

After which you refer to "username" returning "example".

So, in order to return each username, you need to loop over each item in the list provided by data["data"] as shown below:

```
for user in data["data"]:
    print(user["username"])
```